# SQL: Select the highest conditional sum on a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an OrdersProducts tables with `order_id`, `product_id`, and quantity fields. I'd like to know the most popular products, so how can I sum the quantity field for each product_id separately and then order the sums? Any pointers would be appreciated. I'm using MySQL 5.3, thanks.

Comment: +1 for actually naming your table and its columns.  Not enough people do this when asking for SQL help!

Comment: However, are you sure you're using MySQL 5.3?  My understanding is that they skipped from MySQL 5.1 directly to 5.4.

Comment: Whoops. I spent the whole day talking about all the new stuff in PHP 5.3, the number was in my head. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
select product_id, sum(quantity) As ProductQtySum
from OrdersProducts 
group by product_id 
order by ProductQtySum Desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure MySQL will like this - but its pretty standard SQL

```
SELECT product_id, sum(quantity)
FROM OrdersProducts 
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY sum(quantity) DESC
```